# Make the image inside the skewed div normal

Tags: html, css, skew

As the question follows.
I am trying to make the content, which in this case is a image inside a div that is supposed to be skewed.
With other words, the div should be skewed and the image inside of it not.

I am using:

```
-ms-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use skew only in the parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027357/how-to-use-skew-only-in-the-parent-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the opposite value to the child. So add the following to the image:

```
/* positive 15deg */
-ms-transform: skew(15deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(15deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(15deg, 0deg);
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2zu2Lv4d/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did try this before and now again but it makes the use of the command useless since it resets it so the div is not skewed too.

Comment: The image you're talking about is `<img>` or background-image in the div?

Comment: <img> which is inside the <div>

Comment: This is really strange, because I have it like that and the image just resets back to normal when I remove the minus from the child.

Comment: Of course you need to name them, use id and class as you like. But in that link, your div has id "skew", while in the css you used the wrong id which is `#div`, it should be `#skew`

Comment: Yeah saw that, i edited my post. So I tried putting in my stuffs in the jsfiddle and it worked all fine, but it doesnt work when I try it in my browser.

Comment: You probably gave wrong id or class in the html or css. Fix that, then it should work as expected

Comment: Can you see anything wrong?
 Because I can't: https://gyazo.com/ff21ba7307d6adc51937f807f6c97fff

Comment: That's seems correct, but without having the full source code, it's difficult to tell what's wrong

Comment: Thanks for help evilReiko! My class id was "active". IM **** DONE.

Comment: Nevermind, it wasnt that. Here is my full code where it doesnt work: https://gyazo.com/e2c44837b1015c9768da115274b36497