# CSS: Is there a way to use the transform skew property on a specific div without affecting child elements?

Tags: css, transform, transformation, css-transforms, skew

I'm trying to use the transform: skewX property on a div but it also skews the text inside the navigation. Is there a way to apply the transform: skewX property without also affecting the text inside?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="nav" id="skew-left"><p>Test  /  About Me  /  Portfolios  /  Contact Me</p></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.nav {
  background-color: #154360;
  height: 65px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 550px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width:100%;
}

#skew-left {
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to put an absolute positioned element behind the rest and skew that element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use skew only in the parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027357/how-to-use-skew-only-in-the-parent-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can negate the skewing on the child element

```
#skew-left p {
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

Reposition them afterwards as necessary.

Comment: This works, but any text in the "unskewed" elements looks just a little different - like the aliasing has changed, losing a touch of sharpness in the process